# how to get array of table after click button in YII2

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, yii2

This is my form :

```
<div class="mutiple-array-form">
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<table id="sampleTbl", class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr id="myRow">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>william</td>
            <td>32</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Muli</td>
            <td>25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sukoco</td>
            <td>29</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::button('Create',['class' => 'btn btn-success _addNew', 'onclick' => 'myfunction()']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

Below is my Javascript code :

```
<?php  
$script = <<< JS
function myfunction() {
alert(document.getElementById("sampleTbl").rows.namedItem("myRow").innerHTML);
}

JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

My code does not work. When I click button, nothing happens. For example, I want to show table value using array in alert. Please help!

Comment: are u checked out your rendered file, where added your js files. is it right place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying won't work because somehow declaring the function in inline script in yii2 doesnt work,i dont know proper reason of it and i am trying to find the reason.

Now your code will work if you write your script like this

```
<?php  
$script = <<< JS
 $('#idOfButton').click(function(){
      alert(document.getElementById("sampleTbl").rows.namedItem("myRow").innerHTML);
  });
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

And it will only print the value of your header

Now if you want the data of the table inside as an array and alert it, try this code

```
<?php
$script = <<< JS

$('#idOfButton').click(function(){
var myTableArray = [];
$("table#sampleTbl tr").each(function () {
    var arrayOfThisRow = [];
    var tableData = $(this).find('td');
        if (tableData.length > 0) {
            tableData.each(function () {
                arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text());
            });
            myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
       }
    });

    alert(myTableArray);
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

And i would suggest that you use `AppBundle` to use script that way you will be able to debug the code via browser and figure out the problem yourself,which will help you find the answer.

Comment: thank you for your attention, it's work. Next question, i want to save on my database. How to encode Json this array then send to my controller to decode Json then save it? @MikeRoss

Comment: @stfvns see this method `JSON.stringify(yourArray)` and it will convert your array to `JSON`